# recover deleted file on chromebook

Tags: linux, chromebook

I accidentally deleted months worth of work with `rm -r *`. I used it in the wrong directory and now the main Python script that I wrote is gone.

Is there any way to retrieve this whatsoever?
Thanks

(I'm using an asus chromebook)

Comment: Are you able to remove the drive and put it in another PC so you can do a full bitcopy of the drive as a first step?   Once you have an exact copy you can work from without risk to your data you would want to ascertain the filesystem type and see what tools there to help with recovery.

Comment: Note - it is important you stop using the device until you have made a bit copy of it.  Everything you do prior to a bit copy of the device increases the likelyhood of permanent data loss. If you are very lucky the underlying filesystem will be ext4 and you can use extundelete

Comment: _Turn off the computer right now._ This will prevent reuse of now-free disk space and overwriting your file.

Comment: I've had a friend who does this kind of stuff very often look at it, and it is all gone. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Good to know that you are using "a Chromebook" without telling us how you got to a terminal where you can run commands like `rm`. There are several ways. There may be layers of abstraction (hardware, filesystems, virtual machines, more filesystems, garbage collection, containers) involved and your files long gone. Use git, commit often and push to remote locations and have backups. On a plain old computer, trying a recovery tool—which is usually not installed, to make things worse and overwrite data—might be successful. Exporting a btrfs volume which you have little control over… :( Do GIT!

Comment: @davidgo Many cheap Chromebooks have eMMC soldered to the board. High end devices may have NVME, but with the trend to thinner devices the trusty "take the hard drive out" advice may not be fesabile. It could get the user of a device also into trouble if it is a non-privately owned device, which is usually the case. Finally, even thought they are supposed to be general purpose computers or laptops, they are more like tablets or smartphones. Without instructions I'm not going to try to open my Galaxy Chromebook. Many before were maintainable, but I'm sure I'm going to bend or break this one.